# Logging daily check results with changing requirements

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I apologize for the title, but I couldn't think of a better way to ask this question.

Basically, I need to create a database model for logging daily checks and parameters on various pieces of equipment. Every day the user will open up a form, it will list a number of tasks to check as well ask for operating parameters to be recorded (for example, temperature). The user then enters the parameters and flags any item that has an issue.

The issue I have with modeling this is the fact that the items to check can change as operational requirements change. We may need to add or remove things to check to keep things relevant.

I don't really have much example data to show as I am stumped about which way to go. One thing I can think of is keeping some sort of version number but I'm not sure how that would look in a database. The only other thing I could think to do is generate a hard copy PDF of the results and save that, rather than saving the results in the database. That way I don't have to worry about adding/removing items because previous daily checks will not be stored in the database and therefore won't be impacted. This would probably work fine for our needs as we don't have to go back and change anything after it's done, but I can't help to think there is a better way.

Let me know if you need any clarification and thanks for any help you can provide.

**Edit (More Information)**
Right now we have a blank excel sheet for each device, it's got a list of checks... one is say "General cleanup of hydraulic fluid", or "Check for abnormal noise/vibration" then there are a couple that wily say "Hydraulic Pressure (psi)" and you have to enter the pressure you recorded... there's probably about 20 tasks on average. You then put your name on the sheet, date it, print it and sign it.. it gets filled probably to never be seen again....

Comment: creating a pdf of results doesn't really sound like a very good way to model the data if you want to be generating reports that might access the data in a different way than it was originally recorded.

Comment: @Matt - I completely agree, but that's the only real way I can think of at the moment. It's a pretty small aspect of the overall application but I'd like to do it properly for the reasons you mention. Hopefully someone will have done something similar or point me in the right direction. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Cam - If there were 3 checks that were needed for an equipment yesterday and we only need 2 today, does your system need the ability to modify yesterday's checks too.. Or once done, it is in the past and should not be modifiable? From the PDF solution, it looks like the results for a day cannot be reverted back once the required checks change later. Is that true?

Comment: @Rajesh - I don't think there would be a way to modify anything older than the current day (just enough time to fix a mistake, for example). Previous days would be read-only.

Comment: @Cam- So if I'm understanding you correctly, the domain of all things you might be recording is known beforehand but the specific things to be recorded for each day/period might change over time?

Comment: @Matt - Unfortunately not, management may decide that they want to specifically check one component because an issue has been identified with it, then after checking that component for six months may find they no longer need to check it anymore. There's no way to know what will be required ahead of time.

Comment: @Cam But what is the mechanism for actually doing the checks? Are they automated from the aspect that once they are checked in the form you create do they require anymore human intervention? I'll be in the sql-database chatroom if you want to go there and talk about this!

Comment: This reminds me a great deal of a similar question asked a few months ago.  Except in this case, it was sensors that were reporting various readings automatically to a central location.  New sensors were being added all the time, and the statistics provided by the new sensors were contastantly evolving.  The question was how to model this to accomodate all the future statistics.  Maybe soembody else can provide a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cam,

Here is the model/ the list of tables and data that I came up with. I think it covers most of the scnerios/queries that you might use for getting data out of the application.

Equipment table and check tables are two independent entities having the master list of equipment and checks respectively.

### **Setup**

Whenever you have to set up a series of checks for a given equipment, you will insert a new record in the equipment_check_asc table. Since these associations/ checks are time-based, we have an effective date and end-date to determine what are the checks needed at a given point in time and also to keep a historical track of what checks were mandated at that point in time.

### Actual Logging

The actual checks that are made are done using a child table (equipment_check_audit) that records the checks made for each equipment for a given day (whenever they are made).

You can answer the following queries easily from the below model and these are the ones that I could think of.

a) What are the checks needed for this equipment as of today?

b) What were the checks needed for an equipment as of given date

c) Of the required checks, how many were performed and how many were not ( today and any given day ).

d) Of the checks performed, how many passed / failed.

[image]

```
create table equipment(
   equipment_id number primary key,
   equipment_name varchar2(200) not null
   );

create table checks(
   checkid number primary key,
   check_name varchar2(100) not null
  );

create table equipment_check_asc(
   equipment_check_asc_id number primary key,
   equipment_id number not null,
   checkid number not null,
   eff_date date not null,
   end_date date ,
   eff_flag varchar2(1) not null, -- kind of redundant, easier to find the checks effective today.
   constraint fk_equipment_id foreign key (equipment_id) references equipment(equipment_id),
   constraint fk_checkid      foreign key (checkid) references checks(checkid),
   constraint unq_check       unique (equipment_id,checkid,eff_date)
);

create table equipment_check_audit(
    audit_id number primary key,
    equipment_check_asc_id number not null,
    pass_fail_ind varchar2(1) not null,
    audit_date date not null,
    constraint fk_check_id foreign key (equipment_check_asc_id ) references 
       equipment_check_asc (equipment_check_asc_id)
);
```

There might be other corner cases that you might need to cover and model for, but this should give you a general idea.

Here is the data that I tested with.

```
insert into equipment values (1, 'Item 1');
insert into equipment values (2, 'Item 2');
commit;

insert into checks values (100, 'Temperature');
insert into checks values (101, 'Robustness' );
insert into checks values (102, 'Stable'     );
commit;

insert into equipment_check_asc values (1000,1,100,sysdate-10, NULL , 'Y');
insert into equipment_check_asc values (1001,1,101,sysdate-10, NULL , 'Y');
insert into equipment_check_asc values (1002,1,102,sysdate-2 , NULL , 'Y');

insert into equipment_check_asc values (1003,2,100,sysdate-30,  sysdate-1 , 'N');
insert into equipment_check_asc values (1004,2,101,sysdate-30,  NULL    , 'Y');

commit;

delete from equipment_check_audit;

/*** Item A ***/

---checks made on 12/09
insert into equipment_check_audit values (10000, 1000, 'Y', sysdate-5);
---insert into equipment_check_audit(10000, 1000, 'Y', sysdate-5); No checks made on robustness even when it was needed.
-- no check done on stability. (as it was not needed).

---checks made today. (all positives case)
insert into equipment_check_audit values (10001, 1000, 'Y', sysdate);
insert into equipment_check_audit values (10002, 1001, 'N', sysdate);
insert into equipment_check_audit values (10003, 1002, 'Y', sysdate);
commit;

/*** Item B ***/
--checks made on 12/9
insert into equipment_check_audit values (10004, 1003, 'Y', sysdate-5);
--checks made today.
insert into equipment_check_audit values (10005, 1004, 'Y', sysdate);
commit;
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. I really appreciate how much depth you went into for this answer. I like the idea of storing effective dates and just checking that table to see if it was applicable on a given date. Thanks again!

Comment: Wow. Very thorough answer. I would argue that I was telling you a very similar answer. But his is obviously more complete and inclusive of actual schema and design. And I applaud that.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is maybe breaking it down into components...so each device has a list of "tasks" and then each one of these tasks can be created and even reused across multiple devices if you have commonalities. That way if the requirements change you can just create new tasks. It might take a bit of fiddling to develop a UI that looks nice as far as editing and displaying the end result but for modeling purposes i'd say that's the way to go.

I would create a table to store instances of devices, a table to store instances of tasks, and then you would have one other table that connected dates,devices, and tasks. And if a particular task changes itself you have the option of designing it so that way it would be editable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the discussion in the chat room.